# Battery Level of Bluetooth devices using Java

Tags: java, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying build a simple java program which shows battery status of connected Bluetooth devices in **windows**. see bellow sample image.

[image]

First I started with [BlueCove](http://www.bluecove.org/) and realized BlueCove only provides basic information such as address, simple name etc.. after further investigation and found out only way to read the characteristic is via BLE GATT service.
therefore started writing a test code based on [tinyb](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb) which was found in GitHub [Bluetooth-manager](https://github.com/sputnikdev/bluetooth-manager-tinyb) project and it resulted a Exception

so far I have tried this code

```
import org.sputnikdev.bluetooth.URL;
import org.sputnikdev.bluetooth.manager.CharacteristicGovernor;
import org.sputnikdev.bluetooth.manager.impl.BluetoothManagerBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class B2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        new BluetoothManagerBuilder()
                .withTinyBTransport(true)
                .withBlueGigaTransport("^*.$")
                .build()
                .getCharacteristicGovernor(new URL("/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/F7:EC:62:B9:CF:1F/"
                        + "0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb/00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"), true)
                .whenReady(CharacteristicGovernor::read)
                .thenAccept(data -> {
                    System.out.println("Battery level: " + data[0]);
                }).get();

    }
}
```

**Maven**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sputnikdev</groupId>
        <artifactId>bluetooth-manager</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sputnikdev</groupId>
        <artifactId>bluetooth-manager-tinyb</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native libraries for TinyB transport could not be loaded.
    at org.sputnikdev.bluetooth.manager.impl.BluetoothManagerBuilder.loadTinyBTransport(BluetoothManagerBuilder.java:225)
    at org.sputnikdev.bluetooth.manager.impl.BluetoothManagerBuilder.build(BluetoothManagerBuilder.java:190)
    at B2.main(B2.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native libraries for TinyB transport could not be loaded.
    at org.sputnikdev.bluetooth.manager.impl.BluetoothManagerBuilder.loadTinyBTransport(BluetoothManagerBuilder.java:218)
    ... 2 more
```

**My question - >
is there any other way to obtain Bluetooth device battery level using JAVA ?**

Note :

1. There are plenty of examples available in android and python but not for Java / windows
2. Also found unanswered similar C# question
   [Get Bluetooth Device Battery Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463798/get-bluetooth-device-battery-level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of adapters and each of them has pros and cons.

- Generic adapter (Supported by the TinyB Transport). These are the most common adapters, most likely you have one already or it is embedded into your PC/Laptop. However, there is a major drawback - it works only in **Linux** based environments, to be more precise, it requires **Bluez** software installed in your OS.
- BlueGiga serial adapter (Supported by the BlueGiga Transport). This a special type of bluetooth adapters that is quite rare. One of the most common is [Bluegiga BLED112](https://www.silabs.com/wireless/bluetooth/bluegiga-low-energy-legacy-modules/device.bled112). The main criteria in selecting a BlueGiga adapter is that it must support [BGAPI](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2015/08/06/_reference_bgapib-Alq6).

The following table shows some major features supported by each adapter type.
[image: major features supported by each adapter type]

Note:

To use **bluetooth-manager-tinyb**, You must upgrade your Bluez software to 5.43+. This is due to some changes in the DBus API in Bluez 5.43v. (Bluez 5.44v, Bluez 5.45v, Bluez 5.46v, Bluez 5.47v preferred)

Final Note:

Windows OS is not supported by `TinyB transport`. For Windows OS you will need to get a `BlueGiga` adapter. You can use your Intel Wireless adapter in Linux environment only.

Comment: is there any other way to get data from Generic adapter for windows ? maybe from some other langue ? because i have found [this](https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/?v=020a0001&osv=10.0.18362) third party app which works in windows for  Generic adapter

Comment: @aKilleR Try these. [Bluetooth Battery Monitor](https://github.com/joric/bluetooth-battery-monitor),  [How to Read the Battery Level of Bluetooth LE Devices](https://www.andreasjakl.com/read-battery-level-bluetooth-le-devices/)